# lightning-combobox validation - how to reset into no errors

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

I am building LWC component and have a few comboboxes that some of them are required.

```
<lightning-combobox
        required="true"
        label="My combo"
        options={options}
        value={myValue}
        onchange={onChangeOptions}>
```

When the user clicks submit I am executing `inputField.reportValidity();` for all components

Then if the required comboboxes are empty I get error messages:

[image]

All this is ok.

Now, I have also a reset button which should reset all comboboxes to an empty state.

**Problem:**

When I click on the reset button I want also that all the red errors would disappear - like the page has just started.

I am clearing the combobox's value to null, it does not help

I tried also:

```
this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-combobox').forEach(element => {
    element.value = null;
}
```

and it does not help

And tried:

```
this.myValue = null;
```

and it also does not help

**Question:**

Is there a way to make the red error and the red square surrounding the element disapear?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with `inputField.setCustomValidity('')`

Comment: As also stated by dev force , setting customvalidtity to '' should resolve your issue

Comment: @devforce That doesn't work. Because it is not a custom message to begin with, you cannot clear it that way. I tried. I did get it to work via two other ways, though.

Comment: as @sfdcfox said - this is not a custom validity so it does not work

Answer (score 1):

You have two options available to you.

## Option 1

Set the field to a legal value, then wait a tick, use `reportValidity`, then set it back to null.

```
resetField(event) {
  this.myValue = '1'
  setTimeout(() => (this.template.querySelector('lightning-combobox').reportValidity(), this.myValue = null))
}
```

This creates a brief flicker in the field(s) as they are set to a value, then back to null, but the layout remains undisturbed.

## Option 2

Hide the field temporarily, then restore it:

```
resetField(event) {
  // set fields to null here, then...
  this.showForm = false;
  setTimeout(() => this.showForm = true)
}
```

This causes a brief flicker as the elements are taken out of the DOM and put back in again, but will leave the form fully reset. You can put the `if:true` demonstrated above on the form itself, rather than each individual field. This would be a lot easier to manage.

I have confirmed that using `setCustomValidity` by itself is insufficient to clear the error state, because it was not set by `setCustomValidity` initially.

I have created a [custom component](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/bFwjfXMCMzc9tFWmW1eE/src/app.js?p=stories) demonstrating both valid techniques.